# variable in angular service does not work for 2 different call

Tags: angularjs

in first call of getDatas.docData(); form tabcontroller i am able to alert 
email, but in second call getData.getDocData(); it is showing as undefined.

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);

 app.controller("tabController", ['$scope','getDatas','$rootScope', function($scope,getDatas,$rootScope)  {

 $scope.getDocData=function(){  
 getDatas.docData();
 getDatas.getDocData();
 }
 }]);

 app.factory("getDatas",['$http',function($http){
 var docDatas = {content:null};

 return{
docData:function(){
  $http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/doctor/getDocData'
 }).then(function(response) {

  docDatas=response.data;
  //alert(docDatas.name);
})
  },  

getDocData:function(){
alert(docDatas.name);

 }
}

 }]);
```

What am i going wrong some one help. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

js does not wait for this line processed and then process next line because
js is async you should use $q in your factory, in your code maybe this code  "**getDatas.getDocData();**" sooner run than "**getDatas.docData();**" finally js dont find **docDatas.name** and return undefind,
good luck...